# Change system calls function pointers at runtime in Linux

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I have a huge project that is creating a lot of files and folders that I want to track them.
In order to debug the code, I would like to replace a system call behavior to check what is going on.

My idea is to hook a new function in the same place where the system call is being used and see the behavior of the application, after it has started. To be more clear, here is an example of what I need:

The application is creating a annoying folder like /tmp/annoying_folder. So I would like to intercept every mkdir system call and check if the it's argument is the annoying_folder and if it is the case, force it to return an error, so I can locate which process is doing this  and also know it's stack call.

What I have tried up to now is using LD_PRELOAD, which is not working in the case of this application, because it is doing direct system calls, instead of going through libc.

I'm having trouble using gdb, because I'm not sure which process is doing these calls, because the application is started by a script that calls multiple other processes.

Through strace I'm able to see the mkdir call that I'm looking for, but it doesn't help me much, because I need to also know the stack trace call of the application to figure out where is the code that is generating this.

So one option that thought to be interesting is to use LD_PRELOAD to load a library with a constructor function that would change the hook point of mkdir and redirect it to my custom function. But I need directions on how to do that for Linux system calls.

**Do someone knows how to change System calls function pointers at runtime?**

Comment: You could use `LD_PRELOAD` to replace `syscall()`

Comment: "*Through strace I'm able to see the mkdir call*" and "*I'm not sure which process is doing these calls*" seem to be contradictory. If you can strace the process don't you by definition know which one it is and hence can gdb it?

Comment: If could provide me a way to know the PID of the process before it do the call to mkdir, it would be nice. Otherwise I would still not sure which process is doing the call.

Comment: Please clarify how you are able to successfully strace without knowing the process that you want/need to strace. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "System calls function pointers". What are these "function pointers" that you refer to? At the lowest level a syscall assembly instruction will drop into kernel mode. And you can't change what happens after that at user level unless you mean you want to modify the kernel code.

Comment: Imagine you have multiple processes being called by a script. Suddenly one of them call a mkdir("/tmp/annoying_folder"). How can you know which process is going to call this mkdir before it do a actual call? As far as I know I need to attach gdb to the process before it reaches the desired part of the code. My goal is to intercept every call of mkdir before the call is done. Attaching gdb to every process is something that I would avoid, because they are in a really huge amount.

Comment: You are not answering the question. You said "*Through strace I'm able to see the mkdir call*". How are you running strace to be able to see the `mkdir` call if you don't know the process to trace?

Comment: You may consider [System Tap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) which is able to trace system wide.

Comment: If you run "strace -fy <script_path>" you will see every system call from all processes that this script calls, even forks of every process that happens to appear. Since I'm looking into a huge code base (with Java, Python, C++ mixed), I need to know exactly which process is calling the mkdir. Indeed, I have no way to know the PID for a process that is going to create a directory prior to it actually doing the operation. If it were easy, I would just use gdb to follow the process that is creating the directory and everything would be solved. My goal is to track this operation from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to intercept those system calls as I expected, but I've found an interesting workaround with stap utility.

I've created the following script:

```
#! /bin/stap -g

probe nd_syscall.mkdir.return {
  folder_name = user_string(@entry(pointer_arg(1)), "-");
  folder_name_prefix = substr(folder_name, 0, 9);
  if(folder_name_prefix == "/tmp/test") {
    printf("[%d] [%d] [%16s] [%s]\n", uid(), pid(), execname(), folder_name);
    raise(%{ SIGSTOP %});
}
```

Then I was able to send a signal stop to the process and after that connect gdb to analyze the application stack trace.